# Avoid Nulls in Insert Into Select with nested Selects

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to load data from a staging DB into my normalized DB, but some data hasn't been made available for 2018, so I'm trying to adjust my `INSERT INTO SELECT` query to just grab information that already exists in my Database.

I want to be able to insert into my `Game` Table where the Teams I'm adding in exist.

The staged data looks like this:

```
ID     |  GameID        | Visitor  |  Event
____________________________________________
25301  |  BRO192104170  |  BSN     |  Strikeout
25302  |  BRO192104170  |  BSN     |  Hit
25303  |  BRO192104170  |  BSN     |  Homerun
25304  |  BRO192104170  |  BSN     |  Groundout
25305  |  BOS192104180  |  NY1     |  Groundout
25306  |  BOS192104180  |  NY1     |  Lineout
```

I currently have the following `Team` Table as such:

```
ID   |  Team Name         |  RetrosheetID
___________________________________________
100  |  Boston Red Sox    |  BSN
101  |  Brooklyn Dodgers  |  BRO
102  |  New York Yankees  |  NY1
```

I'd like to load the Staged data into my `Game` table (BRO vs BSN shown):

```
ID   |  TeamID  |  DateID  |  OpponentID  |  GameNumberOfDay  |  RetroGameID
____________________________________________________________________________
100  |  101     |  10101   |  100         | 0                 | BRO192104170
```

The issue comes when I need to filter out teams that don't exist in my `Team` table yet, because that data hasn't become available yet.

Below is my current query:

```
select distinct
    (select ID from Statistix.dbo.Team 
        where 
        (
            Year = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4))
            AND
            retrosheet = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 1, 3))
        )
    ) as TeamID,
    (select
        ID
    from Statistix.dbo.Date
        where
        (
            Year = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4))
            AND
            Month = (select SUBSTRING(GameID,8,2))
            AND
            Day = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 10, 2))
        )
    ) as DateID,
    (select ID from Statistix.dbo.Team 
        where 
        (
            Year = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4))
            AND
            retrosheet = Visitor
        )
    ) as OpponentID,
    (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 12, 1)) as GameNumber,
    GameID
from dbo.Events e
where not exists (select * from Statistix.dbo.Game g where g.RetroGameID = GameID)
```

It works if the Teams exist, so I tried adding this to the `WHERE` clause:

```
AND (TeamID IS NOT NULL AND OpponentID IS NOT NULL)
```

However, I get this error message:

> Invalid column name 'TeamID'
>
> Invalid column name 'OpponentID'

Comment: I don't see an actual problem statement here.  What is your query supposed to be doing?  Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've just edited my question to show sample staged data, `Team` and `Game` tables

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked:

```
select distinct
    (select ID from Statistix.dbo.Team 
        where 
        (
            Year = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4))
            AND
            retrosheet = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 1, 3))
        )
    ) as TeamID,
    (select
        ID
    from Statistix.dbo.Date
        where
        (
            Year = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4))
            AND
            Month = (select SUBSTRING(GameID,8,2))
            AND
            Day = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 10, 2))
        )
    ) as DateID,
    (select ID from Statistix.dbo.Team 
        where 
        (
            Year = (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4))
            AND
            retrosheet = Visitor
        )
    ) as OpponentID,
    (select SUBSTRING(GameID, 12, 1)) as GameNumber,
    GameID
from dbo.Events e
where not exists (select * from Statistix.dbo.Game g where g.RetroGameID = GameID)
and exists (select * from Statistix.dbo.Team t where t.retrosheet = (SELECT SUBSTRING(GameID, 1, 3)) and t.Year = (SELECT SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4)))
and exists (select * from Statistix.dbo.Team o where o.retrosheet = Visitor and o.Year = (SELECT SUBSTRING(GameID, 4, 4)))
```